# redirecting to aspx page in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, response.redirect

I have a MVC3 application. Outside the views folder i created a folder called Reports and inside Reports i added an Index.aspx page with the ViewUserControl and here i call SQL server reporting service. I have StatisticsController and View where I select parameters and then in Controller redirect to .aspx page with this parameters. It's working on local machine but when I put it to the external server i get error page:

> Server Error in '/Reports' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Reports/Index.aspx

Further in the controller i used a function as given below:

```
    public ActionResult PacStatRep1(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
    {
        string CustomerNumber = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id;
        string url = "~/Reports/Index.aspx?CustomerNumber=" + CustomerNumber + "&dateFrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateTo=" + dateTo;
        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

Any suggestion how to access this page? Dont't know if it is redirection issue or iis issue or something else.

Comment: I have considered solutions from added answer but don't work on external server. Like I said it works on localhost but when I put it on external server in other domain i get Server Error: Server Error in '/Reports' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Reports/Index.aspx

Comment: The problem was the name of folder with Index.aspx - shouldn't be named Reports. After renaming the folder works perfect.